# Refresh Angular2 page programmatically without all app reloading

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

What is a method to refresh a route in Angular 2 programmatically in order to trigger onInit hook?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: I need to refresh the page after get authorization token from server if authorization token expires. I have got method for that but don't know how to refresh the current view after getting right token.

Comment: You could just do data-binding. I still don't see a necessity to reload anything. Just use a share service with an `EventEmitter` to allow components to subscribe changes.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is a good solution but with more code. Maybe there is a single method to just refresh the current route.

Comment: @KrzysztofSaja have you got answer ?

Comment: it's possible !  see [Angular 2 routing to the same route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225119/angular-2-routing-to-the-same-route/37225256#37225256)

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe there is a single method to just refresh the current route.

From:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html

> `renavigate() : Promise<any>`
>
> Navigates to either the last URL successfully navigated to, or the
>   last URL requested if the router has yet to successfully navigate.

Inject the router and call the `renavigate()` method:

`this._router.renavigate();`

Comment: I've already tried this one but router.renavigate() seems to work only if url is  changed. Otherwise it is like double clicking a route link - it doesn't do anything.

Comment: The same as with renavigate

Comment: same does't work properly. on clicking back button of browser.

Comment: @all Take a look at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831#issuecomment-319634921 for how to trick the router into reloading the current view

Answer (score 0):

works for angular 5+ :

1) add `runGuardsAndResolvers` to your route:

```
const routes: Routes = [   { path: '', component: YourComponent, runGuardsAndResolvers: "always" } ]
```

2) add `onSameUrlNavigation` property to routes import

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

3) now navigating to your url using `navigateByUrl('current url')` reloads the page for you.