# Angular 2 routing to the same route

Tags: angular

I have `Ride` component, and in the end of the ride the `Ride Summary` is shown.

The right summary has a button to "Start another ride" which redirects to the same component, `Ride`.

```
[routerLink]="['Ride']"
```

Since the `Ride` component is already the one i'm in, it's not refreshed and the `Ride Summary` screen is keep showing.

How I can re-init the `Ride` component when re-navigating to it? (use again the ngOnInit method)

Answer (score 4):

`Router` doesn't navigate if the `route` and `params` haven't changed, by default.

---

To make it navigate you can define

```ts
routerCanReuse(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction, 
               prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction){
  return false;
}
```

in your component, that you want to renvaigate to, and call

<strike>`Router.renavigate();`</strike>

```ts
this.router.navigate('RouteName', this.routeParams.params)
```

to renavigate.

Comment: I've been thinking on it, but it does't feel right. I have no need in a parameter, so making a counting number of rides parameter is innecessary and I'm looking for alternative, cleaner way for re initation of the route.

Comment: updated my answer, see if it works, it didn't for me when I tried.

Comment: @TheUnreal why would you want to route to the same route without changing anything. That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'll be more than happy to explain; The current route, `Ride`, is showing a ride. when user ends the ride, I hide the main view of the `Ride` component and I show <ride-summary></ride-summary> instead. Although the ride summary is shown, the route is still `Ride`. The buttons in my ride summary need to start a new ride, which means - re init the current route - which is `Ride`. The ride starts in the `OnInit()` Method of the ride component.

Comment: @A_Singh Hi, Do you happen to know how to do this with the newest router? It doesn't seem to have `ComponentInstruction`, nor does it seem to allow specifying the `routerCanReuse` anywhere.

Comment: unfortunately I've not jumped upon new Router yet, srry :)

Comment: @TheUnreal  I'm curious as to why you would not just have the ride-summary component as its' own route and navigate to it.  If it's data retention that you are worried about, you can stash the data in a local cache, server cache, or use the browser's IndexDB.  That way you can view the ride summary even if you didn't just finish the ride.  It would also remove the need for a less than optimal solution.  Am I missing something?

Comment: if only angular2 made it easy to actually reset dropdown forms to initial data value...