# How to reload a page in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to reload a page in angular2.
While searching through net, i got a code `"this._router.renavigate()"` to reload the page but looks like its not working with latest release of angular2.
Another way is `'window.location.reload()'` but this is not the angular way of doing it.

Comment: There is no Angular way of reloading the page, because usually you wouldn't want to do that in an Angular application. What's the use case?

Comment: `renavigate()` is also not supposed to reload the page, only to navigate to the same path again. A page reload is something different because it would re-initialize the whole Angular application.

Comment: use case:  always up application / kiosk.  need a way for the app to self-update

Answer (score 14):

If you really want to reload the page you need to run location.reload() outside the angular zone

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    location.reload();
});
```

tested with RC6

**Full Example**

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";

@Component({        
    templateUrl: "template.html"    
})
export class ReloadComponent{
    constructor(
        private zone: NgZone) {
    }

    reloadPage() { // click handler or similar
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            location.reload();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnak you. It really helped. The only thing that worked. You are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

For partial there is way to write your own function

```
   public renavigate(): void {
   let params: Object = {};
   Object.assign(params, this.routeParams.params);
   params['ref'] = (params['ref'] === ref) ? ref + new Date().getTime() : ref;
   this.router.navigate(['Foo', params]);
   }
```

Comment: Angular 2 routerCanReuse now can help to navigate on same Url: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37225256/5868331

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
method().subscribe(
   location.reload();
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is what worked for me:

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) {}

ngOnInit() { this.load(); }

load() {
  this.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's about toogle the visibility with

```
   *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()"
```

that makes a much better UX

Answer (score -2):

location.reload() will reload the page.